# Styling a search box inside a header with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to style a search box inside a header using CSS. Here is a picture of my problem to help try and make things clearer:

When the search box is visible:
[image: When the search box is visible]

So my main problem is when the search box is faded in using JQuery it is taken out of document flow because I am using `position: absolute;` on `.topSearchBarResultWrapper` to get the search box where I want it on the header. I have tried using `position: relative;` which does bring the element `.topSearchBarResultWrapper` back into flow but does not display the search results below the header.

Thus, when I use position relative I did try and use `top: 80px;` to bring the search box wrapper down and then use `margin-top: -100px;` to get rid of the extra white space above, but then when you add search results to the wrapper the `top: 80px;` is invalid and does not work anymore because the size of `.topSearchBarResultWrapper` has changed.

I have also made a JsFiddle to help as well: https://jsfiddle.net/jjzp07ey/

Here is my HTML code that I am using:

```
<header> <!-- HTML 5 header -->

        <ul class="navigationBarButtons">

            <li> 

                <a class="topSearchBarButton defaultBlueButton navLoginButton"><img src="images/icons/searchIcon.png"></a> 

                <div class="topSearchBarResultWrapper">

                    <input type="text" class="topSearchBarInput" name="topSearchBox" placeholder="Search for someone...">

                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>
                    <div class="topSearchBarResult">d</div>

                </div>

            </li>

            <li> <a class="defaultBlueButton" href="profileranks.php">Profile Ranks</a> </li>

            <li> <a class="defaultBlueButton" href="howitworks.php">How it Works</a>    </li>

        </ul>

    </header>
```

And here is the CSS code that I am using:

```
.topSearchBarInput
{
    height: 32px;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.topSearchBarButton img
{
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.topSearchBarResultWrapper
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #dad9d5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

.topSearchBarResult
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}

header
{
    background-color: black;
}

header ul
{
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

header li
{
    display: inline;
}

.defaultBlueButton /* Default Button Style */
{
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9); /* Used to support many different browsers */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5;
    -moz-border-radius: 5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0px;
}

.defaultBlueButton:hover
{
    background: #3cb0fd;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db); /* Used to support many different browsers */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: _"Not Going to post code here..."_ - then I'm afraid your question will be closed as off-topic. Please provide a [MCVE] _within your question_.

Comment: Don't see the point but there we go...

Comment: The point is; if you link to an external site and that site goes down or is unreachable for any reason, your question becomes entirely useless to future visitors who may have the same problem.

Comment: OK Fair enough, I agree.

Comment: I have now reworded my entire question and hope that it follows the rules.

Comment: Much better. I've nominated the question to be re-opened. It will take another 4 votes from other users before it is re-opened.

Comment: Ok thank you, sorry for not following and creating a decent question the first time round.

Comment: By any chance would you know where I could look, as I am really stuck on this :/